# Parsing XML with ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic, xml-parsing

I have the code below, I just need help on figuring out the best way to get html from the content node below instead of plaintext.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
sKey = objItem.GetAttribute("id")             
Title = objItem.selectSingleNode("title").text
Blurb = objItem.selectSingleNode("blurb").text
Content = objItem.selectSingleNode("content").text
Image = objItem.selectSingleNode("image").text
myDate = objItem.selectSingleNode("date").text
myMonth = objItem.selectSingleNode("month").text
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best way of handling XML with Classic ASP is to use an XSL stylesheet.

XSLT is quite easy to learn at a basic level, although the learning curve gets a bit steeper later on.

I recommend the w3schools tutorial

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Once you've written your stylesheet, if you have a local XML source your asp code would look like this

```
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")
xml.load(Server.Mappath("source.xml"))
set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")
xsl.load(Server.Mappath("stylesheet.xsl"))
Response.Write(xml.transformNode(xsl))
set xsl = nothing
set xml = nothing
```

If the xml is from a remote url then it's a little more complex

```
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")
xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
xml.async = false
xml.validateOnParse = false
xml.load("http://xmlsource.com")
set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")
xsl.load(Server.Mappath("stylesheet.xsl"))
Response.Write(xml.transformNode(xsl))
set xsl = nothing
set xml = nothing
```

Edit

```
<h2><%= Title %></h2>
```

Comment: That is nice, I will use for my own, code, but I inherited the code above and would rather not re-write the system

Comment: Once you've defined your variables, as you have, then you can always just embed them in html, see my little edit above.  Or are your nodes inside repeating elements?

Comment: It is in a for loop.  I thought I could just switch .text to .html like in jquery, but I was wrong

Comment: There's an old script here for parsing RSS feeds in pure asp code, there might be something you can use in it.  https://web.archive.org/web/20060204123026/http://www.html.dk/scripts/asp/00020/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the XML of a node using the `xml` property instead of the `text` property you are using now:

```
    dim o_xml, o_node
    set o_xml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")
    o_xml.load("books.xml")
    set o_node = o_xml.selectSingleNode("//catalog/book[@id='bk102']")
    Response.Write Server.htmlEncode(o_node.xml)
```

Docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms755989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx