# The most basic way to read XML and store as VB variables

Tags: html, xml, vb.net

So I've got a XML file that looks like this:

```
<response>
<led0>0</led0> 
<led1>1</led1> 
<pot0>0.0</pot0> 
<pot1>0.0</pot1> 
<temp1>22.2</temp1> 
<temp2>***</temp2> 
<temp3>***</temp3> 
</response>
```

All I'm trying to do is store each of these lines in the XML as a variable in VB.

For example : Line 3 in the XML would = Dim LED1 in VB.

So that they can then be more easily used in a Web Application.

I've tried looking online but there doesn't seem to be a simple solutions for this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Presumably you just looking for an example of how to read from xml?

Comment: There are several options you can use.  The simplest ones would be either `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, or `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: See this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411840/parsing-xml-with-asp

Comment: VB.Net or ASP-Classic? You'll get two very different answers. Fix your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have zero flexibility on the model:

Using your original xml file

```vb
Private Sub testXmlReadingAndWriting()
    Try
        Dim filename As String = "<your file name here>"
        Dim myResponse As Response = Nothing
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Response))
        Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)
            myResponse = CType(serializer.Deserialize(sr), Response)
        End Using
        myResponse.led0 = 0.7
        myResponse.temp3 = 23.ToString()
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(filename)
            serializer.Serialize(sw, myResponse)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Exception handled: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

<XmlRoot("response")> _
Public Class Response
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public led0 As Single
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public led1 As Single
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public pot0 As Single
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public pot1 As Single
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public temp1 As String
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public temp2 As String
    <XmlElement()> _
    Public temp3 As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer for if you have flexibility on the model:

Using Xml Serialization, you can have a strongly typed representation of your xml in memory (variables, as you asked).

Consider this XML:

```xml
<response>
  <measurement Type="Led" Index="0" Value="0" />
  <measurement Type="Led" Index="1" Value="1" />
  <measurement Type="Pot" Index="0" Value="0" />
  <measurement Type="Pot" Index="1" Value="0" />
  <measurement Type="Temp" Index="1" Value="22.2" />
  <measurement Type="Temp" Index="2" Value="0" />
  <measurement Type="Temp" Index="3" Value="0" />
</response>
```

Using xml model classes, you can serialize and deserialize from xml to variables. Here's the code to read from xml, modify the values, and write to xml:

```vb
Private Sub testXmlReadingAndWriting()
    Try
        Dim filename As String = "<your file name here>"
        Dim myResponse As Response = Nothing
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Response))
        Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)
            myResponse = CType(serializer.Deserialize(sr), Response)
        End Using
        myResponse.Measurements.Add(New Measurement(2, 0.7, MeasurementType.Led))
        myResponse.Measurements.Add(New Measurement(2, 10700, MeasurementType.Pot))
        myResponse.Measurements.Add(New Measurement(4, 23, MeasurementType.Temp))
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(filename)
            serializer.Serialize(sw, myResponse)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Exception handled: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

<XmlRoot("response")> _
Public Class Response
    <XmlElement("measurement")> _
    Public Measurements As List(Of Measurement)
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Measurement
    <XmlAttribute> _
    Public [Type] As MeasurementType
    <XmlAttribute> _
    Public Index As Integer
    <XmlAttribute> _
    Public Value As Single
    Public Sub New(index As Integer, value As Single, [type] As MeasurementType)
        Me.Index = index
        Me.Value = value
        Me.[Type] = [type]
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Enum MeasurementType
    Led
    Pot
    Temp
End Enum
```

I realize I modified your xml model, but this makes for a more flexible model.